# English US language code changed? Google Speech Api v2 not returning the correct result

Tags: android, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Just noticed the English US words no longer display the correct spelling. This previously was ok - now it displays the English UK spelling. Below is a list of some words that I found .For example if I say **center**  and set the language code as en-US I am getting the result as **centre** which is English UK.

I am using Google api v2

https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-US&key=my_key"

WORDS ENDING IN –RE

British English words that end in -re often end in -er in American English:

**British**  and   **US**

```
centre          center 

fibre           fiber 

litre           liter 

theatre         theater or theatre
```

Even though I am giving the language code as en-US the result returned will be in British English.Is this a common issue or US English code is no longer working. Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

I just noticed this issue is with ok google also Even though my input is in English us ,the answers I am getting is in English Uk.These are some other words

Words ending in -our

British English words ending in -our usually end in -or in American English:

**British**     and    **US**

```
colour        color

flavour       flavor

humour        humor

labour        labor

neighbour     neighbor
```

Verbs in British English that can be spelled with either -ize or -ise at the end are always spelled with -ize at the end in American English:

**British**      and             **US**

```
apologize or apologise      apologize

organize or organise        organize

recognize or recognise      recognize
```

Words ending in -yse

Verbs in British English that end in -yse are always spelled -yze in American English:

**British**      and         **US**

```
analyse              analyze

breathalyse          breathalyze

paralyse             paralyze
```

Comment: Try en-us: `lang=en-us`

Comment: already tried but no luck..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution for it.I know most of the people don't just care if the result is in English UK or English US.But the problem was my app is a spelling app .So showing English UK words for English US language was a big problem for me.And the solution is really simple just get rid off Locale when English US is selected,ie replace **en-US** to **en** and your speech recognizing url looks like this https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en&key=my_key. And use the locale for all other languages like **en-GB** for uk English.

**Edit**

Change url to

https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=0000&key=my_key .

Hoping this lasts longer.